# Как узнать длину или ключ последнего элемента в ветке Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Как узнать длину или ключ последнего элемента в ветке Firebase? В примере это "4". В приложении они добавляются по порядку, поэтому нужно узнать под каким индексом создавать сдежующий ключ.

```
 {
    "Question_Score" : {
        "1" : {
          "1": {
            "score" : "50",
            "user" : "user1"
          },
          "2": {
            "score" : "50",
            "user" : "user2"
          },
          "3": {
            "score" : "50",
            "user" : "user3"
          },
          "4": {
            "score" : "40",
            "user" : "user4"
          },
        },
      }
    }
```

Comment: посомтрите здесь
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601147/get-last-node-in-firebase-database-android